# the development server returned response error code: 500 -React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing Android app using React Native. I tried running a simple code of a screen being displayed, but I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bXnS.png). I tried closing all command line windows and emulator and re-starting React Native package and run it, but doesn't work. The code is provided below:

**index.android.js:**

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, AppRegistry,Button} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import dhrumil from '.\dhrumil.js';

export default class MainApp extends Component{
render(){
  return(
    <dhrumil />
  );
}

}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: dhrumil }
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent("MainApp",()=>SimpleApp);
```

**dhrumil.js:**

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, AppRegistry,Button,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const dhrumil = () =>{

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.texter}>Hello World!</Text>
    <Button
        onPress={() => navigate('dharmin')}
        title="Chat with Lucy"
      />
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1
  }
  texter:
  {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});


dhrumil.navigationOptions = {
  title:'dhrumil'
}
export default dhrumil
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.android.js` change the `import dhrumil from '.\dhrumil.js';` to `import dhrumil from './dhrumil';`. You have to use `/` to specify the path and it is not necessary use `dhrumil.js` when we are importing the `js` file.

Comment: Yeah I just found that mistake. That was a silly mistake. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

@Jeffrey Rajan 's suggestion was absolutely correct here.

This error occurs mostly due to :
Issue 1:

1. A wrong file name in import statement
2. Using the wrong case in file name
3. Using '\' instead of '/' in file name

Hope that using this list you can easily find errors causing this in your code.

Issue 2:
An issue with the material design.To resolve this install material design locally using :

`react-native-material-design`

Issue 3:
babel-preset-react-native making trouble code. To resolve this issue run:

```
yarn remove babel-preset-react-native

yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

Try troubleshooting in this order.Mostly the Issue 1 will solve the problem.

Comment: Hi please do suggest more items on the list if you have come across any.I have listed all the issues I have encountered till now and how I have fixed them.